# How to remove empty column with heading?

Tags: excel

I have column headings like Material 1, Material 2,... Material 15. Below these headings if there is no data i.e. if the column is empty. Then the entire column should be deleted automatically.

Example : if the Material 5, Material 7, up to Material 15 columns are empty then they should be deleted.

I was trying the below code, however its not working till Material 15 column it stops after deleting 2 or 3 columns. Kindly help me.

```js
Sub clearcol()
On Error Resume Next
 Dim lRealLastRow, lRealLastCol As Long
    lRealLastRow = Cells.Find("*", Range("A1"), xlValues, , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row
    lRealLastCol = Cells.Find("*", Range("A1"), xlValues, , xlByColumns, xlPrevious).Column
    For i = 1 To lRealLastCol
        If lRealLastRow - WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(Intersect(Columns(i), ActiveSheet.UsedRange)) <= 1 Then _
            Columns(i).EntireColumn.Delete
    Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider this alternative:

```
Sub KolumnKiller()
    Dim N As Long, i As Long, Kount As Long
    Dim wf As WorksheetFunction
    Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction
    N = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    For i = N To 1 Step -1
        Kount = wf.CountA(Cells(1, i).EntireColumn)
        If Kount = 1 Or Kount = 0 Then
            Cells(1, i).EntireColumn.Delete
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you delete one column, and increment the counter at the same time, you skip some columns. To fix it, reverse the order of `For` loop

```
For i = lRealLastCol To 1 Step -1
```